# Is impact parameter a initial condition for collision in colliders?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, experimental-physics, collision, large-hadron-collider

In colliders what is the initial condition for 2 electrons collision ([Møller scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8ller_scattering)).

I know that the momentum is one the initial condition but what about impact parameter?

For example if we have two electrons with momentum $p$ and $-p$ and their vertical distance (impact parameter) are high enough, the interaction will be almost zero.

Do they take in account this in colliders like LHC?

Answer (score 0):

By classical mechanics, the impact parameter is the distance of line of the free movement to its parallel line through the collision center.

The impact parameter,  as a vector,  cross multiplied by momentum, is the angular momentum vector with respect to the collision center.  Its square $L^2/(2m r^2)$ is the angular kinetic energy in spherical coordinates by

$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m} +V(r) = \frac{p_r^2}{2m} + \frac{L^2}{2m r^2} +V(r)$$

All that remains true in quantum mechanics. Large angular momentum yields states $r^n e^{- \alpha_n r} Y_{l,m}$, that have a low concentration near the collision center and a small effective collision cross section.